# Using Beamer to step through an algorithm written in pseudocode.

Tags: beamer, pseudocode

I am trying to create a beamer presentation in which I would step through an algorithm, highlighting the current line in the algorithm on each slide. I know it is possible to do with the `semiverbatim` environment, however, my algorithm has to be written in pseudocode.  I am trying to match the pseudocode format that is used by the textbook I am using, and for that the `algpseudocode` package that is a part of the `algorithmicx` package seems to do an excellent work.

However, I cannot figure out how to highlight the current line in the `algorithmic` environment. I tried to do this:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\section{Blah}
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Blah}
   \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{.4\hsize}
    \begin{algorithmic}
       \alert<1>{\State $z \gets 1$}
       \alert<2>{\For{$i = 1 \to n$}}
       \alert<3>{\State $z \gets z + \frac{1}{i}$}
       \alert<4>{\EndFor}
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{column}%
 \begin{column}{.6\hsize}
    Some text discussing the current line.
 \end{column}
   \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

however that gives me an error about missing `\endcsname`. Does anybody have any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `algorithmic` environment needs to be able to "see" the commands `\State`, `\For`, `\EndFor` at the top level.  It doesn't like having them in the `\alert` environments.  One way around this is to simulate the alerting by merely changing the text colour on each line.  Here's a way to do it:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\alertline}{%
 \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}%
 \only{\usebeamercolor[fg]{alerted text}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Blah}
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Blah}
   \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{.4\hsize}
    \begin{algorithmic}
\alertline<1>\State  $z \gets 1$
\alertline<2>\For    {$i = 1 \to n$}
\alertline<3>\State  $z \gets z + \frac{1}{i}$
\alertline<4>\EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{column}%
 \begin{column}{.6\hsize}
    Some text discussing the current line.
 \end{column}
   \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This approach doesn't work if you want the background to be highlighted as that puts the text in a `\colorbox` which seems to hide it from the `algorithmic` environment.

(Note: my suppositions about what's happening are based purely on observation and not on any knowledge of what's going on under the bonnet.)

Comment: Overlays don't work, when they are used inside \For, \If, etc. But when you wrap the whole \For, \If it works like a charm

Comment: What do you do if you need to highlight a line twice, e.g. a for-loop you might need to highlight the inner part more than once. I've tried this with your solution, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what kind of overlay do you prefer, but it works with  using `\uncover`:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\section{Blah}
\begin{frame}{Blah}
   \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{.4\hsize}
    \begin{algorithmic}
       \uncover<1>{\State $z \gets 1$}
       \uncover<2>{\For{$i = 1 \to n$}}
       \uncover<3>{\State $z \gets z + \frac{1}{i}$}
       \uncover<4>{\EndFor}
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{column}%
 \begin{column}{.6\hsize}
    Some text discussing the current line.
 \end{column}
   \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For me at works also with `\alert` (but not in the case of `\IF` when using the `algorithmic` package)