# How to hide LaTeX commands and keywords in a listing?

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I highlight some lines from source code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code)

How to hide LaTeX command (keywords) in a listing? When I use for example **\textbf{}** in the listing it appears as `\textbf{}`. How can I hide this?

Comment: I think there's a new Tex/Latex StackExchange site these days... may be a better place to ask

Comment: See the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code , it should apply to this question, too.

Comment: Given that this is an old question and the context is not overly clear, I'm minded to close this as a duplicate of the question that Jan links to.  Any objections?

Comment: @Andrew: agreed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that you can.  The listings package provides its own macros for emphasising words in source code listings.  For example, by default it emphasises language keywords.  You can alter or add to the words that the pakcage emphasises.  The following snippet, from the listings documentation,

```
\lstset{emph={square,root},emphstyle=\underbar}
```

will cause listings to set the words `square` and `root` with an underline.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
How to hide Latex Command (keywords) in a Listing. 
When i user for example \textbf{} the in the listing 
wil be appereard \textbf{}. How can hide this?
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While hard to discern from the way the question was phrased, I believe the OP wanted to format text inside a TeX code listing *made with the `listings` package*. And of course, when he/she tried to do that, the commands appeared as they are, and no formatting took place.