# Source Code Margin Comments

Tags: listings, marginpar, comments

In the paper "Beautiful Code Compelling Evidence", by J.R. Heard -- Code is formated in a particular way which includes margin comments. I am looking for a way to do this as I think it is a very clear way to comment comment code in a literate programming style.

Comment: See this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code/8860#8860 with the listings package you can include TeX commands using "funny eyes". Simply include a `marginpar` or a `sidenote` if your class has one.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Related Question: [Code region comments left of a listing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210419/code-region-comments-left-of-a-listing).

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned already in the comments you can use `escapeinside` option of `lstlisting` (`listings` package) to execute own code inside a code listing. There are also `executebegin` and `executeend` to insert code automatically before and after such markers.

My idea:
 * Use `minipages` to restrain the listing to less than the text width and move it to the right using some horizontal space.
 * A separation line like in the linked paper can be added using the `frame=l` option.
 * Use the above commands to add comments at the beginning of code lines.
 * The automatic added code places the comments to the left using `\llap{<content>\hspace{<distance>}}` without taking up any official space.
 * To allow multi-line comments an extra `minipage` with correct alignment is added around the comments.

The code would look like this: (first listing only supports single line comments while the second supports multi-line comments!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % better tt fonts!

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\makeatletter
\def\comsep{\dimexpr\lst@numbersep+\lst@frametextsep\relax}% most likely not correct!
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\hspace*{.3\linewidth}%
\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=l,basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=C,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    escapebegin={\begin{lrbox}{0}\normalfont\itshape\small\color{black!70}},
    escapeend={\end{lrbox}\llap{\box0\hspace{\comsep}}}
    ]
(*@ Declare it   @*) int i = 0;
(*@ useless!     @*) i + i;
(*@ increment    @*) i++:

(*@ now print it @*) print i;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\hspace*{.3\linewidth}%
\lstset{% set here because `\linewidth` has still its old value
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    escapebegin={\begin{lrbox}{0}\minipage[t]{.3\linewidth}\raggedleft\normalfont\itshape\small\leavevmode\color{black!70}\ignorespaces},
    escapeend={\endminipage\end{lrbox}\llap{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\box0}\hspace{\comsep}}}
}%
\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=l,basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=C]
(*@ Declare it   @*) int i = 0;
(*@ useless!     @*) i + i;
(*@ increment; more text more    @*) i++:

(*@ now print it @*) print i;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

This looks as follows:

[image: Result]

If this is used more often a new environment could be defined (`\newlstenvironment`) or the settings can be set globally.

Note: In theory this could be hacked deeper into the `listings` code to allow the comment to be added at the end instead of the start. This would simplify the adding of comments but would be much more difficult to code.

Comment: (+1) I was about to ask a similar question! In ConTeXt, I used to rely on custom `paragraphs` (usually defined as `\defineparagraphs[ecode][n=2,rule=on]`) to create such side-by-side layout but I guess the above code could be translated to ConTeXt without too much difficulty. It has the merit of having the code and associated comments on the same line.