# Align minipage to baseline of first or last line inside minipage?

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning, boxes, minipage, varwidth

The `minipage` environment has options for making the top, bottom, or center of the minipage box line up with the baseline of the surrounding text.  Is there a way to make it line up to the baseline of the first or last line of text inside the minipage?

I imagine I'd use `\raisebox`, but how do I calculate the distance from the top of the minipage to the first line's baseline (or the bottom of the minipage to the last line's baseline)?

### Update:

As indicated in the excellent answer below, `minipage` already does what I want.  The problem I had was that the `\color` command was messing with the minipage in all sorts of bizarre ways.  Putting a `\strut` at the beginning and end of the minipage didn't fix it, but everything started working once I changed `\color` to `\textcolor`:

[image: Picture illustrating how color broke things]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newcommand{\sampletext}{testing (1)\\testing (2)}
\newcommand{\tmp}[2]{\fbox{\begin{varwidth}[#1]{0.8in}#2\end{varwidth}}}
\newcommand{\broken}[1]{\tmp{#1}{\color[rgb]{0,0,0.5}\sampletext}}%
\newcommand{\fixed}[1]{\tmp{#1}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.5}{\sampletext}}}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\begin{document}
with \verb|\color|:\\
before \broken{t} between \broken{c} between \broken{b} after

with \verb|\textcolor|:\\
before \fixed{t} between \fixed{c} between \fixed{b} after
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `[t]` and `[b]` optional arguments of `minipage` already use the baselines of the first and last line, and not the top or bottom of the surrounding box. AFAIK most of such vertical positioning options in LaTeX address baselines. Here three `minipage`s with `[t]`, `[c]` (or without) and `[b]` options (code below):

[image: Result]

If this wouldn't be the case I would use `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}{<content>}` and `\raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\dp\strutbox\relax}{<content>}` for the first and last baseline, respectively. This depends on the content, but would be accurate if both lines contain a `\strut`.

---

#### Update:

About the issue with `\color`: This macro apparently adds some vertical space because at the beginning of `minipage` TeX is still in vertical mode. To avoid this use `\leavevmode` before `\color` (as `\textcolor` does internally). This will change to horizontal mode and avoid the misalignment. Added a `\strut` before `\color` should actually do the same, because it also starts horizontal mode.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

before
\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    First\\
    Middle\\
    Last
\end{minipage}
between
\begin{minipage}[c]{1cm}
    First\\
    Middle\\
    Last
\end{minipage}
between
\begin{minipage}[b]{1cm}
    First\\
    Middle\\
    Last
\end{minipage}
after

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right.  Something else must be messing with my minipage then, because it's aligning to the absolute top/bottom of the box, not the baseline of the first or last line.  I'll have to figure that out.

Comment: @Richard: You might have something in it which creates vertical space, e.g. `\vspace*{0pt}` leads to your described behavior. See [Aligning image and text on top, with minipages(http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages/11631#11631) where this technique is used for vertical alignment. My tip: Try to start and/or end the `minipage` with a `\strut`.

Comment: It was `\color`'s fault.  Switching to `\textcolor` fixed it.  Adding `\strut` to the beginning and end of the `minipage` didn't work.

Comment: @Richard: Coincidently I ran into the exact same issue of a broken `minipage` alignment with an included `\color` at the beginning when I was answering [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/source-code-margin-comments/22082#22082). There a `\strut` before the `\color` actually fixed it.

Comment: @Richard: Found it: `\textcolor` is basically only `\leavevmode {\color #1{#2}#3}`. The `\leavevmode` is the important here. Without TeX is still in vertical mode when `\color` is processed and this adds some vertical space somehow.

Comment: Changing `\color{...}text` to `\leavevmode{\color{...}text}` worked!

Comment: @Richard: Great. Note that `\leavevmode` doesn't take any argument, so you can simply write `\leavevmode\color{...}text`.

Comment: I tried leaving out the brackets but it didn't work.  However, moving the first bracket to before `\leavevmode` (so that it became `{\leavevmode\color{...}text}`) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is interesting the varwidth package that you propose, i think however on subject, "The minipage environment" place de column in the same level, i work with this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

My trick is input [t] option in same cases, with the others i have troubles.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in my opinion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please elaborate on your answer. As it stands it's probably no solution