# Minipage content overlaps with text before that if nccmath is used

Tags: positioning, minipage, nccmath

It seems that if the `nccmath` package is included, then the text in the following minipage [overlaps with the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td7JB.png) before that if the minipage contains only display math.  The `\FixMinipageForNccmath` macros is from [nccmath affecting minipage widths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22102/nccmath-affecting-minipage-widths).

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preview=false]{standalone}%
%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{nccmath}% Needed for fleqn environment

\newcommand*{\FixMinipageForNccmath}{\hrule height 0pt width \hsize}%

\begin{document}
Some text: $2 \ln x = 1$

\begin{minipage}{0.70\linewidth}\FixMinipageForNccmath
\begin{align*}
       \ln x &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}\FixMinipageForNccmath
    Note: abcd
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that **nccmath** has serious bugs. The `\hrule` has no influence, as you probably have already noticed.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I [posted to see if there is a replacement package for nccmath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath)

Comment: @egreg: It seems if I just use `\newcommand*{\FixMinipageForNccmath}{\leavevmode}` both of the recent problems get fixed. I don't quite understand what other impacts this would have but got the idea from [this recent question about aligning minipages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22071/align-minipage-to-baseline-of-first-or-last-line-inside-minipage)

Comment: @egreg: If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it so we can move this to answered.

Comment: @PeterGrill: What about using `etoolbox` and `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minipage}{\leavevmode}`?

Comment: @Bernard: Yep, as per my comment above that was the solution I was using, but I then have since moved on from `nccmath`.

Comment: @Peter Grill: not sure to get all. You mean using etoolbox &c. provides a solution, at least to the minipage problem?

Comment: @Bernard: I believe that it did, but I think I was only applying it if needed, not applying it to all `minipages`.

Comment: @Peter Grill:Do you think adding to nccmath this simple patch to minipage could be harmful in any way? I don't know enough of the internals of LaTeX to have an opinion.

Comment: @Bernard: This is an issue from 2.5 years ago and I don't fully remember the details. Also, I don't know the TeX internals so am not qualified to comment on that. Perhaps you should post a new question and get info from those who really understand this. I have moved on from `nccmath` and am no longer using it. I just point out the problems I encountered in case those using it also run into the same problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that **nccmath** has serious bugs. The `\hrule` has no influence, as you probably have already noticed.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is due to `\NCC@ignorepar` command in `nccmath` package:

"This command removes extra vertical space before display formula if it starts from a new paragraph and changes the beforeskip to \abovedisplayshortskip if the \useshortskip command was applied."

`\let \NCC@ignorepar=\relax` should fix the problem.