# Is there a replacement for nccmath?

Tags: minipage, nccmath

I noticed that the [`nccmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) package is not mentioned in [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex).  Since I have had several problems with `minipages` that all eventually led to `nccmath` related issues, I am wondering if this package is still being maintained, or if there is a replacement package that should be used instead.

The problems I have had had include:

1. [Minipage content overlaps with text before that if nccmath is used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22167/minipage-content-overlaps-with-text-before-that-if-nccmath-is-used),
2. [nccmath affecting minipage widths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22102/nccmath-affecting-minipage-widths), and
3. [Alignment of item number in list containing a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/alignment-of-item-number-in-list-containing-a-minipage)

Comment: As `nccmath` is a collection of rather independent enhancements to `amsmath`, a "replacement" will depend on the feature(s) needed by you. That said, have a look at [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `nccmath` is a collection of rather independent enhancements to `amsmath`, a "replacement" will depend on the feature(s) needed by you. That said, have a look at [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).