# How to reduce the size of fractions typed in align environment?

Tags: amsmath, align, fontsize, fractions

When digit fractions align environment, this goes with a size `\displaystyle`. But I want the size is like the one shown in a paragraph. I tried with `\scriptstyle` but I get letters too small and the `\small` command not working under `align` environment. 
What I can do? Here I put a screenshot, lines down, to further clarify this idea and my question. 
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\rightarrow \quad &x=3,\frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}.   \tag{1}\\
\end{align*}
This is a text in paragraph: $\textrm{C.S}=\{3,\frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}.\}$

\end{document}
```

[image: my screenshot]

Comment: Yes, use `\textstyle` within the `align` environment.

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much. `\textstyle` works.

Comment: `amsmath` also provides the `tfrac` command, which sets a fraction in `textstyle` independent of the environment (conversely, `dfrac` always uses `displaystyle`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another solution if you find there figures in textstyle too small: the \mfrac command,defined in the nccmath package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, textcomp} 

\begin{document}

Here’s an align environment typeset first with \verb+\mfrac+, then  \verb+\tfrac+ 
and finally\verb+\mfrac+: 
   \begin{align*}
   \rightarrow \quad &x=3, \frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}.  \\
   \rightarrow \quad &x=3, \tfrac{10}{3},\tfrac{11}{3}. \\
   \rightarrow \quad &x=3, \mfrac{10}{3},\mfrac{11}{3}. \\
   \end{align*}

This is a text in paragraph typeset with \verb+\tfrac+: $\textrm{C.S}=\{3,\frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}\}$.  

This is a text in another paragraph typeset with \verb+\mfrac+: $\textrm{C.S}=\bigl \{3,\mfrac{10}{3},\mfrac{11}{3}\bigr\}$. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Comparison between the 3 types of fractions]

Comment: Many thanks. But with `\mfrac` the numerator is located relatively high in the line of division of the fraction. 
You can control the vertical space between the numerator and the division line of the fraction on `mfrac`?

Comment: No more no less as with \dfrac: roughly, it is a \dfrac in a (general) fontsize reduced by 20%. But I haven't really studied the code.

Comment: @mathsalomon: FYI, When I started out, I made use of the `nccmath` package, but ran into numerous problem and since then have changed all my code to not use it. See [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath) and the other linked questions there.

Comment: @Peter Grill I didn't know about these problems between minipage and nccmath. That said, I very rarely use minipage since it is unbreakable across pages. I mainly use the ‘medium size’ math possibilities of ncc math. Do you know if loading the package is enough to have problems, or if it is only the use of certain commands/environments that results in problems?

Comment: I thought I could configure that. Well I think it is not of much importance. It is a very small defect because `\mfrac`  works OK with algebraic fractions, in this case they the fractions are perfectly distributed. Thanks guys for the comments .

Answer (score 6):

You can use `textstyle` to ensure that the math is typeset as it would have been within a paragraph:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
 \rightarrow \quad &x=3, \textstyle\frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}.   \tag{1}\\
\end{align*}
This is a text in paragraph: $\textrm{C.S}=\{3,\frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}.\}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's just what I wanted.

Comment: `\tfrac{..}{...}` also works since `amsmath` is being used.  (it used `\textstyle` internally.)