# Equation is being shrunk to fit sentence, how can I prevent that?

Tags: math-mode

I should preface that I discovered LaTeX a few hours ago but I've googled and searched the documentation and haven't found an answer. Here is the line I've written

```
Question 1: $\int \frac{x-3}{x^2-6x+5} \mathrm{d}x$
```

When I compile and view as a pdf, the equation has shrunk to fit the sentence and it's difficult to make out because it's so small. Is there a way I can have the equation and text on the same line while having an equation that's the same size as if I used:

```
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{x-3}{x^2-6x+5} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
```

?

Comment: `$\displaystyle....` will do what you ask, but normally it's a bad idea as it will mess up the line spacing of the paragraph

Comment: Is this what you want: `$\displaystyle\int \frac{x-3}{x^2-6x+5} \mathrm{d}x$`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/586

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, 2 seconds!!?? lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also an intermediate solution with the `nccmath` package, which defines `medium sized mathematics`. These medium sized formulae do not have the same effect on interlinespacing as `\displaystyle`, and usually have none if this spacing is globally slightly increased with the `\setstretch{…}`command from the `setspace`package. Compare with this code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

   \usepackage{nccmath} 

    \newcommand{\dd}{\,\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\mint}{\medint\int}

    \begin{document}

    Let's compute  $ \int\! \frac{x-3}{x^2-6x+5} \dd x $  or  $ \mint\! \mfrac{x-3}{x^2-6x+5}  \dd x$  or even $\displaystyle \int \!\frac{x-3}{x^2-6x+5}\dd x$. 

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, this is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The package can also be interesting in displayed formulae, e.g. when you have a factor 1/2 in front of an expression: often you do not want it in displaystyle, but textstyle is really too small. In such a case, `\mfrac{1}{2}` is a good solution.

Comment: @user47989: Before you start using `nccmath` too much in your code I thought I'd refer you to: [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath). I was using `nccmath` for a while but then abandoned it due to the problems listed in that question.

Comment: @Peter Grill; Iwasn't awware of those problems – I must say I almost never use minipage. To my eyes, the most interesting feature is the possibility of medium sized mathematics, and to a lesser extent, the `\useshortskip` command. Unfortunately, `mathtools` (which should be recommanded rather than the bare `amsmath`, in my opinion) doesn't have these features.