# How to format this formula, in particular, the parentheses better?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

```
 $$\mathrm{err} \left( h(\vec{\theta}, \vec{x}), y \right)
= \delta_{0y} ~ H \left( h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}) - \frac{1}{2} \right)
+ \delta_{1y} ~ H \left( \frac{1}{2} - h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}) \right)$$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You should never use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)
2. “err” should be a math operator.
3. Never use a `~` in math mode; multiplication doesn't want space.
4. `\left` and `\right` add unwanted space when they surround the argument to a function.
5. A `\vec` near a closed parenthesis needs a thin space.
6. There's no need to have big parentheses for the argument to `err`; I'd use normal size, but I show also how to get slighly bigger ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\err}{err}

\begin{document}
First version
\[
\err( h(\vec{\theta}, \vec{x}\,), y )
= \delta_{0y} H \biggl( h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}\,) - \frac{1}{2} \biggr)
+ \delta_{1y} H \biggl( \frac{1}{2} - h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}\,) \biggr)
\]

Second version
\[
\err\bigl( h(\vec{\theta}, \vec{x}\,), y \bigr)
= \delta_{0y} H \biggl( h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}\,) - \frac{1}{2} \biggr)
+ \delta_{1y} H \biggl( \frac{1}{2} - h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}\,) \biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other options include not having `\DeclareMathOperator{\err}{err}` in the preamble but the equivalent `\operatorname{err}` in the formula and using `\tfrac{1}{2}` as suggested by daleif, although I'm not sure about this. Here's the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

Third version
\[
\operatorname{err}\bigl( h(\vec{\theta}, \vec{x}\,), y \bigr)
= \delta_{0y} H \bigl( h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}\,) - \tfrac{1}{2} \bigr)
+ \delta_{1y} H \bigl( \tfrac{1}{2} - h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}\,) \bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost identical to what I was about to post, the only addition I had was to add phantom vertical spacing on the vector arrows `\vec{x\vphantom{\theta}` so that they are the same height.

Comment: @PeterGrill I wouldn't do it; I wouldn't use the arrow for the vector, either.

Comment: @egreg: once more I forgot to check if an answer was posted while I was checking mine! However I have smaller parentheses through the use of  `nccmath` for fractions.

Comment: Would look even better using \tfrac

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of `\[` and `\]`.  I had been using `$` and `$$` and it seems to do the job without me noticing anything wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to not use `\DeclareMathOperator` but do it all in that equation itself?

Comment: @Problemania For `$$` see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503); for the operator you can use `\operatorname{err}` in the formula, which is better than `\mathrm` in this case (and is equivalent to what you get if you define `\err` as shown in the preamble).

Answer (score 2):

Supposing it is a LaTeX document, first replace `$$ … $$` with `\[ … \]`. Also define `err` as a math operator to have a correct horizontal spacing. Then you can use the `nccmath` package to use medium sized fractions, and replace `\left … \right` with the manually adjusted `\Bigl … \Bigr`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath} 

\DeclareMathOperator{\err}{err}

\begin{document}

\[ \err\bigl( h(\vec{\theta}, \vec{x}), y \bigr) = \delta_{0y}\,H\Bigl(h( \vec{x}; \vec{\theta}) - \mfrac{1}{2} \Bigr) + \delta_{1y}\, H\Bigl( \mfrac{1}{2} - h(\vec{x}; \vec{\theta}) \Bigr) \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, I used to use [the `nccmath` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath)
package but ran into numerous issues that I decided to drop it. See [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath) and the problems listed in the question.

Comment: @Peter Grill: I know that (can't remember under which exact circumstances, but I never met those difficulties). The closest would be the `\mathsmaller` command from `relsize`. Maybe you should try to contact the author of nccmath — in my opinion, this concept of medium sized math formulae is really useful, as you can see from this example.