# Set spacing after intertext between split environments with nccmath package

Tags: spacing, align, split, intertext

How would I set the vertical spacing after intertext to the same amount as for the first equation? Using `\\` gives to much vertical space plus adds a new equation what i do not want ofc. Without `\\` there's no space at all. 
Without the `nccmath` package everything works fine, but I really like to keep the `\mfrac{}{}` statements. Also the blank line before align is mandatory to recreate the issue.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{eurosym,bm,amsmath}     % Mathematische Notationen
\usepackage{nccmath} %<------- causing the issue (needed for \mfrac)

\begin{document}

Für das Forget Gate ergibt sich das Resultat dabei durch

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\hat{f}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)f}_k + \sum_{l} \omega^{(i)f}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + \sum_{l} \nu^{(i)f}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
f_{t,k}^{(i)} &=  \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{f}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right) 
\end{split}
\intertext{analog erhält man auch für das Input Gate}
\begin{split}
\hat{i}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)i}_k + \sum_{l} \omega^{(i)i}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + \sum_{l} \nu^{(i)i}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
i_{t,k}^{(i)} &=  \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{i}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right) 
\end{split}
\intertext{ebenso wie für das Output Gate}\\
\begin{split}
\hat{o}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)o}_k + \sum_{l} \omega^{(i)o}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + \sum_{l} \nu^{(i)o}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
o_{t,k}^{(i)} &=  \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{o}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right) 
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please start by making your MWE compilable. Using the `article` class and adding `amsmath` I only see an issue with ``\intertext{...}\\`` which is resolved by removing the ``\\``

Comment: With your latest MWE I do not get the image you posted.

Comment: You're right, me neither, even if I include all my settiings and packages I dont get that missing space. No clue why it happens in my main document though...

Comment: You have to keep trying. Unless you can recreate the issue, we cannot help.

Comment: finally found it, after reducing the million packages and settings step by step. Problem comes from the `nccmath` package which I use for `\mfrac{}{}` Seems very strange to me as I dont even use `\mfrac` in here

Comment: For me your new MWE still does not give that missing space. I get a double space after the second `\intertext` because of the ``\\`` fur the first has the space it should have.

Comment: okay it only occurs with the blank space before align and nccmath, I added that now, I know those are not recommended, but I like them to keep a structure in my tex file as i use tons of align environments

Comment: you should never have a blank line before a display math in TeX: that produces a spurious empty paragraph, that looks like vertical space

Comment: strange though the blank line but without nccmath works well. Is there any filling line instead of the blank that you'd recommend to keep the structure? Something short that doesnt mess up the formatting?

Comment: no even in plain tex with no packages at all, a blank line before display math will do the wrong thing.

Comment: FYI, I used to use [the `nccmath` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath)
package but ran into numerous issues that I decided to drop it. See [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath) and the problems listed in the question.

Comment: thanks for the hint, as far as I know I am only using the \mfrac function, maybe I'll find somethin equivalent.

Comment: In addition to the spurious paragraph, a blank line before *any* display math environment permits a page break, which is almost never desirable, since the display should be interpreted as a continuation of the text in the paragraph which precedes it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities: `nccmath` adds an optional argument to  `\intertext`, which is added to the vertical spacing of this command. You also can use the `spreadlines` environment, from `mathtools` , which adds a vertical spacing  (mandatory argument) between all rows of an amsmath environment.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{eurosym,bm, mathtools} % Mathematische Notationen
\usepackage{amssymb,verbatim}
\usepackage{amsthm} % Beweise / Theorem
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

Für das Forget Gate ergibt sich das Resultat dabei durch
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\hat{f}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)f}_k + ∑_{l} \omega^{(i)f}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + ∑_{l} \nu^{(i)f}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
f_{t,k}^{(i)} &= \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{f}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right)
\end{split}
\intertext[3ex]{analog erhält man auch für das Input Gate}
\begin{split}
\hat{i}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)i}_k + ∑_{l} \omega^{(i)i}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + ∑_{l} \nu^{(i)i}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
i_{t,k}^{(i)} &= \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{i}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right)
\end{split}
\intertext[3ex]{ebenso wie für das Output Gate}
\begin{split}
\hat{o}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)o}_k + ∑_{l} \omega^{(i)o}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + ∑_{l} \nu^{(i)o}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
o_{t,k}^{(i)} &= \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{o}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right)
\end{split}
\end{align}

Für das Forget Gate ergibt sich das Resultat dabei durch
\begin{spreadlines}{2ex}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\hat{f}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)f}_k + \sum_{l} \omega^{(i)f}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + \sum_{l} \nu^{(i)f}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
f_{t,k}^{(i)} &= \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{f}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right)
\end{split}
\intertext{analog erhält man auch für das Input Gate}
\begin{split}
\hat{i}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)i}_k + \sum_{l} \omega^{(i)i}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + \sum_{l} \nu^{(i)i}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
i_{t,k}^{(i)} &= \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{i}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right)
\end{split}
\intertext{ebenso wie für das Output Gate}
\begin{split}
\hat{o}_{t,k}^{(i)} &= b^{(i)o}_k + \sum_{l} \omega^{(i)o}_{kl} x^{(i-1)}_{t,l} + \sum_{l} \nu^{(i)o}_{kl} x^{(i)}_{t-1,l} \\
o_{t,k}^{(i)} &= \varphi_{sig}\left( \hat{o}_{t,k}^{(i)} \right)
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{spreadlines}%

\end{document}
```

[image]