# How to properly subscript in a superscripted fraction?

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, superscripts, fractions

the title says it all. It attached a MWE to display the different relative sizes of a subscript within a normal fraction and a superscripted fraction. As you can see, in the superscripted fraction the subscripted letters have the same size as the other letters. How can I change them to be smaller?

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
    $e^\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}$
    $\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}$
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\displaystyle` won't help you here, since your fraction is in the exponent.

a recommended approach when `$e$` is involved is to use the operator name "exp":

```
$\exp\left(\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}\right)$
```

`\exp` is already defined in plain tex and latex.

Comment: I have seen similar style even when representing `$2^{...}$` as `$\exp_2(...)$`, like an analogue of `\log_2`.

Comment: @Aditya -- eek!  i think this is going a bit far ... it certainly isn't a recommendation in swanson's *mathematics into type*, whereas `\exp` for the exponential function definitely is.

Answer (score 3):

Two-story fractions in exponents are not recommended; it's better to use the slash form

```
\[ e^{E_{A}/(k_{B}T)} \]
```

or maybe

```
\[ \exp(E_{A}/(k_{B}T) \]
```

are clearer.

Comment: The `nath` can automatically do that, but the display equations part of nath clashes with amsmath. I wish someone would copy the other goodies from nath into a package that does not clash with amsmath.

Comment: Two-story fractions in exponents are not recommended _by whom_? I personally like them better than the slash form in most circumstances, just not in inline math. — What I'd recommend is to not write the Boltzmann constant `k_{B}`, but that's for the sake of the physics involved rather than for typographic reasons.

Comment: @leftroundabout For instance, the TeXbook, pages 140 and 141; exercise 17.1, in particular. It's just a matter of opinion, though. I *don't* like them, so we're even. :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, if the code snippet

```
$e^\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}$
```

is processed in TeX's inline math mode (as above), you can't get the subscripts `A` and `B` to be typeset in an even smaller font size becausethey're already at their smallest possible size. If for some reason you can't follow the advice provided by some of the other answers, I suggest you try the following. A reason the typeset formula is a bit hard to parse/read is that the horizontal space between the `E` and subscript `A`, and between the `k` and the subscript `B` is quite large. (This happens because both subscripts happen to be uppercase letters with bottom serifs that stick quite out to the left.) This can be remedied nicely by putting a negative `thinspace`, `\!`, before each of the subscripts' arguments, as follows:

```
$e^{\frac{E_{\!A}}{k_{\!B} T}}t\frac{E_{\!A}}{k_{\!B} T}$
```

IMHO this looks much easier to parse (when it's typeset, of course!).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to be in inline math mode you should use display math mode `\[`.  Another way to make it clearer would be to add a `\left(` and `\right)` which will place a re-sizing parenthesis around the exponent.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
    \[e^\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}\]
    \[e^{\left(\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}\right)}\]
    \[\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}\]
  \end{document}
```

Alternatively you could use

```
\DeclareMathSizes{display size}{text size}{script size}{scriptscript size}
```

in your preamble to adjust the size globally of each component.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning the `nccmath` package; you can find documentation [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath). This allows you to get different size fonts into fractions, binomials, matrices, etc. I've put them
line by line for comparison. With respect to fractions the `\dfrac` command seems to resolve your issue. The problem which arises when the exponent crowds out the base can be solved as mentioned by egreg: putting the argument in `exp()`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
$e^\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}$\\\\
$e^{\mfrac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}}$\\\\
$e^{\dfrac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}}$\\\\
$\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}$\\\\
$\mfrac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}$\\\\
$\dfrac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}$\\\\
$\exp\left(\dfrac{E_{A}}{k_{B} T}\right)$\\\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Before you use `nccmath`, please see [minipage content overlaps with text before that if nccmath is used](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22167/minipage-content-overlaps-with-text-before-that-if-nccmath-is-used) and [nccmath affecting minipage widths](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22102/nccmath-affecting-minipage-widths).  I was using `nccmath` but since have eliminated it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with subscript/superscript, I made a package to make my life easier. You can easily put fraction in super and sub script.

I made a [Webpage](https://vigou3.github.io/actuarialsymbol/) to explain the package. It's design for actuarial symbol but the output for your problem seem really nice with it.

All you need is the actuarialsymbol package.

At the beginning of the code you have to write

```
\usepackage{actuarialsymbol}
```

The arguments of the function to write sub/superscript

```
\actsymb['subscripL']['superscriptL']{<middle>}{'subscriptR'}{'superscriptR'}
```

Example of output:

```
\actsymb{e}{}[\frac{E_{A}}{k_{B}}]
```

[image]

The CTAN :
http://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol