# "just right" integral sign for tikz integrator block

Tags: tikz-pgf

Goldilocks question:

I want an integral sign and dt that looks good in a block diagram; the `inline` size looks too small and the `displaystyle` size looks too big. Is there any way I can scale it somehow to be between the two?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto, font=\sffamily,
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    blockheight/.style = {
        minimum height=10mm
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        blockheight,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    }
    ]
\node (int1) [block, label=below:too small]{$\int dt$};
\node (int2) [block, right=of int1, label=below:too big]{$\displaystyle\int dt$};
\node (int3) [block, right=of int2, label=below:just right]{???};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\usepackage{nccmath}` you can type

```
$\medint\int dt$
```

in the third box and the result will be

[image]

Goldilocks is wrong here: the right one is in the middle.

Comment: Have the serioeus bugs in `nccmath` as mentioned in [Minipage content overlaps with text before that if nccmath is used](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28246/4301) been addressed? I still avoid this package due to the issues I have encoutered such as those mentioned in [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22170/4301).

Comment: @PeterGrill No idea. I never use `nccmath`, to be honest. And you can see from my answer that I don't really like the output.

Comment: Ahh... I missed the subtly in your answer.

Comment: but I do like it, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JasonS I was afraid you would say it. `;-)`

Comment: Maybe the mathematicians like the `\displaystyle` case and control engineers like the `\medint` case.

Answer (score 4):

A `\scalebox` should suffice.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto, font=\sffamily,
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    blockheight/.style = {
        minimum height=10mm
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        blockheight,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    }
    ]
\node (int1) [block, label=below:too small]{$\int dt$};
\node (int2) [block, right=of int1, label=below:too big]{$\displaystyle\int dt$};
\node (int3) [block, right=of int2, label=below:just right]{$\scalebox{1.4}{$\int$}dt$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]