# algorithm and tikzpicture side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, algorithms, algorithmic

How can I put minipage and tikzpicture side by side? I would like the right picture to centre (now it is aligned to the top) and give it a figure environment so I can give it a caption. This caption should be only under the right picture. What should I do?

```
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{Exact Invariant Simulator} \label{alg:eisim}
            \begin{algorithmic} 
                \FOR{$r \in \{1,2,...,R\}$}
                \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(1,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim p(\theta_i)$
                \STATE Sample $Y^{(1,r)}\sim p(\cdot|\theta_i^{(1,r)})$
                \FOR{$s \in \{2,3,..,S\}$}
                \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(s,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim K_i(\cdot|\theta_{-i}^{(s-1,r)})$
                \ENDFOR
                \STATE Calculate test statistic $T(\theta^{(S,r)}, Y^{(S,r)})$ \footnotemark
                \ENDFOR 
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{40pt}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[latent] (y) {$Y$};
        \node[latent, above = of y] (theta) {$\theta$};
        \edge {theta} {y}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: You could put the figure in a second minipage (really making it a figure with caption) and use [these insights](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22072/121799) to get your desired vertical alignment. If you want more input, consider posting an MWE, i.e. a document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. I do not want to have to guess what the settings for your algorithm are.

Answer (score 2):

The core of that answer is essentially my comment above. The main challenge was to guess all the Ti*k*Z styles and options for your algorithm. Do you really think that this is the job of those who try helping you with your problem?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}  
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{caption} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{Exact Invariant Simulator} \label{alg:eisim}
            \begin{algorithmic} 
                \FOR{$r \in \{1,2,...,R\}$}
                \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(1,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim p(\theta_i)$
                \STATE Sample $Y^{(1,r)}\sim p(\cdot|\theta_i^{(1,r)})$
                \FOR{$s \in \{2,3,..,S\}$}
                \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(s,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim K_i(\cdot|\theta_{-i}^{(s-1,r)})$
                \ENDFOR
                \STATE Calculate test statistic $T(\theta^{(S,r)}, Y^{(S,r)})$ \footnotemark
                \ENDFOR 
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{40pt}
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ latent/.style={circle, draw ,inner sep=4pt,align=center}]
        \node[latent] (y) {$Y$};
        \node[latent, above = of y] (theta) {$\theta$};
        \draw (theta) edge[-latex] (y);
        \node[below=8pt of y] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{A figure}
    \end{minipage}      
\end{document}
```

[image]