# How to write pseudocode similar to code presented in "Beautiful Code" by J. R. Heard

Tags: pseudocode

I came across an astonishing piece of text, which is called ["Beautiful Code, Compelling Evidence" by J. R. Heard](http://www.renci.org/wp-content/pub/tutorials/BeautifulCode.pdf). I was wondering if there is a package or something that allows me to present my code similar to how J. R. Heard presented his code.

I would like line numbering though, but I figured first I need to find what he used to create a formatting like this. Note: the code is Haskell, but I would like to use it for pseudocode.

PS: it would be ideal if line numbering can be done after the vertical line. But I was also wondering whether it is possible to literally fix the width of the left column.

An example from his amazing work is shown below:
[image: Example from Beautiful Code by J. R. Heard]

Thanks for your time and effort to help me!

Comment: `listings` or `minted` are the two usual packages for highlighted code listings

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking specifically how to format the comments as in the screen shot (to the left of the code, separated by a vertical line, automatic line wrapping)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: After a lot of experiments and search for specific solutions I found a complete solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/source-code-margin-comments

Comment: While this is close to the mentioned duplicate, additional code is required to get line numbering working correctly.  I am therefore voting that this question should be left open.

Comment: Did you try asking the author?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't use the Haskell highlighting offered by `listings`, because it highlights too many words (like List, etc.) which are not highlighted in the example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV13]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,listings,xcolor,lipsum}
% Fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Gill Sans Std}
\setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter OT}
% Colors
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{404040}
\definecolor{rulegray}{HTML}{DADADA}
\definecolor{keywordblue}{HTML}{1F497C}
% Listings
\lstdefinestyle{code}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{keywordblue},
  keywords={import,qualified,as,do,where}
}
\newcommand\clearlines[1]{%
  \if#10\else%
    \leavevmode\\%
    \expandafter\clearlines\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1}%
  \fi}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
    \color{darkgray}\raggedleft\itshape
    imports, aliases (1-3) \clearlines{5}
    Split all lines in the file. (6-7) \clearlines{3}
    Insert them into the map (9)
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill{\color{rulegray}\vrule}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.73\linewidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=code]
import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BStr
import qualified Data.Map as Map

readDatafile name = do
    sheet <- (map (BStr.split '\t') . BStr.lines) `fmap`
              BStr.readFile name
    return $ foldl’ go Map.empty sheet
  where go m (x:xs) = Map.insert (BStr.unpack x) xs m
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

Adapting [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22082/10995) to a similar question one can obtain a simpler version:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV13]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,listings,xcolor,lipsum}
% Fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Gill Sans Std}
\setmonofont{Lucida Console}
% Colors
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{404040}
\definecolor{rulegray}{HTML}{DADADA}
\definecolor{keywordblue}{HTML}{1F497C}
% Listings
\lstnewenvironment{beautifulcode}{
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{keywordblue},
    keywords={import,qualified,as,do,where},
    frame=l,rulecolor=\color{rulegray},framesep=.5em,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    escapebegin={\begin{lrbox}{0}\normalfont\itshape\footnotesize\color{darkgray}},
    escapeend={\end{lrbox}\llap{\box0\hspace{1em}}}
  }
  \hspace*{.25\linewidth}
  \minipage{.75\linewidth}
}{
  \endminipage
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{beautifulcode}
(*@imports, aliases (1-3)@*)import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BStr
import qualified Data.Map as Map

readDatafile name = do
(*@Split all lines in the file. (6-7)@*)    sheet <- (map (BStr.split '\t') . BStr.lines) `fmap`
              BStr.readFile name
    return $ foldl’ go Map.empty sheet
(*@Insert them into the map (9)@*)  where go m (x:xs) = Map.insert (BStr.unpack x) xs m
\end{beautifulcode}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

May be you want to try with a `tcblisting` from [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). Next it's just an starting point which will need a lot of customization.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{Heardlisting}[2][]{%
empty,
boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxrule=2pt,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,
lefthand width=.4\linewidth,
segmentation engine=path,
segmentation style={solid,line width=1pt},
comment side listing,
fontupper=\itshape\sffamily,
listing options={% put any listing options here
    language={Haskell},
    aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible},
comment={#2},#1
}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{Heardlisting}{%
   \begin{tabular}{r}% 
      imports, aliases (1-3)\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
      Split all lines in the file. (6-7)\\ \\ \\ 
      Insert them into the map (9)
   \end{tabular}
}
import data.List (foldl`)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BStr
import qualified Data.Map as Map

readDatafile name = do
       sheet <- (mat (BStr.split `\t`) . BStr.lines) `fmap
                      BStr.readFile name
       return $ foldl`go Map.empty sheet
  where go m (x:xs) = Map.insert (BStr.unpack x) xs m
\end{Heardlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, I introduce the `pcodeinput` environment to set up the parameters, while lines of code are introduced with `\pcode[comment]{code}` within the environment.  This has the advantage over other approaches of co-locating the comment with the code in your source document.

User parameters include

```
\leftcodesize=1.7in\relax
\leftcodegap=8pt\relax
\rightcodegap=10pt\relax
\coderulewidth=1pt\relax
\def\codecolor{blue!30!black!65}
\def\highlightcolor{blue!70!black!99}
```

to define the width of comments, the gaps around the bar separator, the separator-bar width, and the colors of code and highlighted code.

My twist for this approach was adapting the `\titlecap` routine of the `titlecaps` package for text highlighting.  In that package, `\titlecap` capitalizes each word except those provided for in a user-specified lower-case-word list.  Here, `\titlecap` gets transformed into `\colorize`, where highlight words are added with the syntax `\AddHighlightWords{import qualified as do where}`.  Words not in the list get colorized with `\codecolor`, whereas words on the list get colorized with `\highlightcolor`.  Note that `\colorize` is built into the `\pcode[]{}` definition and so it is transparent to the user.

This is not a `verbatim` environment, so special provisions need to be taken.  For example, I made `$` which appears in the OP's example into catcode 12.  This can be done for other needed symbols, as well, except for the backslash.  In this case (since it seemed a rare occcurence in the OP's code), I entered it as `\textbackslash` in the code listing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newlength\leftcodesize
\newlength\leftcodegap
\newlength\rightcodegap
\newlength\coderulewidth
%%% USER PARAMETERS
\leftcodesize=1.7in\relax
\leftcodegap=8pt\relax
\rightcodegap=10pt\relax
\coderulewidth=1pt\relax
\def\codecolor{blue!30!black!65}
\def\highlightcolor{blue!70!black!99}
%%%
\newcommand\pcode[2][]{%
  \fboxsep=0pt%
  \fboxrule=.5\coderulewidth%
  \makebox[\leftcodesize][r]{%
    \scriptsize\sffamily\itshape#1\hspace{\leftcodegap}}%
  \smash{\fbox{\strut}}%
  \hspace{\rightcodegap}%
  \ttfamily\small\colorize[n]{#2}\par%
}
\newenvironment{pcodeinput}
{\parindent 0pt\parskip 0pt\color{\codecolor}\medskip%
  \catcode`$=12}
{\medskip}
%%
\makeatletter
% ADAPT THE \titlecap ROUTINE FROM titlecaps PACKAGE
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\newcommand\colorize[2][P]{%
  \digest@sizes%
  \if T\converttilde\def~{ }\fi%
  \redefine@tertius%
  \get@argsC{#2}%
  \seek@lcwords{#1}%
  \if P#1%
    \redefine@primus%
    \get@argsC{#2}%
    \protected@edef\primus@argi{\argi}%
  \else%
  \fi%
  \setcounter{word@count}{0}%
  \redefine@secundus%
  \def\@thestring{}%
  \get@argsC{#2}%
  \if P#1\protected@edef\argi{\primus@argi}\fi%
  \whiledo{\value{word@count} < \narg}{%
    \addtocounter{word@count}{1}%
    \if F\csname found@word\roman{word@count}\endcsname%
      \textcolor{\codecolor}{\csname arg\roman{word@count}\endcsname}
      \expandafter\protected@edef\csname%
           arg\roman{word@count}\endcsname{\@thestring}%
    \else
      \textcolor{\highlightcolor}{\csname arg\roman{word@count}\endcsname}
      \expandafter\protected@edef\csname%
           arg\roman{word@count}\endcsname{\@thestring}%
    \fi%
  }%
  \def\@thestring{}%
  \setcounter{word@count}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{word@count} < \narg}{%
    \addtocounter{word@count}{1}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{word@count} = 1}%
   {}{\add@space}%
    \protected@edef\@thestring{\@thestring%
      \csname arg\roman{word@count}\endcsname}%
  }%
  \let~\SaveHardspace%
  \@thestring%
  \restore@sizes%
\un@define}
\makeatother
\let\AddHighlightWords\Addlcwords
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\AddHighlightWords{import qualified as do where}
\begin{pcodeinput}
\pcode[imports, aliases (1-3)]
{import Data,List (foldl')}
\pcode%
{import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BStr}
\pcode
{import qualified Data.Map as map}
\pcode
{}
\pcode
{readDatafile name do}
\pcode[Split all lines in the file. (6-7)]
{    sheet <- (map (BStr.split `\textbackslash t') . BStr.lines) `fmap'}
\pcode
{             BStr.readFile name}
\pcode
{    return $ foldl' go Map.empty sheet}
\pcode[Insert them into the map (9)]
{  where go m (x:xs) = Map.insert (BStr.unpack x) xs m}
\end{pcodeinput}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]