# Listing sourcecode - two columns, associations with colored background

Tags: listings, sourcecode, comments

I stumbeled over a way of formatting sourcecode in a book I am currently reading. It looks like this:
[image: example]

So basically we have a following structure:

- There are two columns. Left column contains the code, right contains the comments
- A comment can be assigned to a line **or** a block of code
- The background color is adjusted to the box of associated parts (gray box in the example)
- Line numbers for each line of code

Does anybody at least know a template which looks like this? So I would have a point where I could start of.

Currently I am using verbatim `lstlisting`. But if there are any other packages, which are more suitable for that kind of formatting code, I would not mind using them either.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210284/10995 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15688/10995

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Though there are some issues with given examples. I liked the structure of writing `(*@comment@*) code` in the latter example. What I did not like is the fact, that I could not put code in separate file e.g. code.cpp: `begin{beautifulcode} some code here end{beautifulcode}}` and including it via `include{code.cpp}`. And I also have no idea on how to put a background on a group of comment + code.