# LaTeX, two-column listing in an array

Tags: listings

I am trying to display to codes side-by-side, using this:

```
\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{c|c}  \begin{lstlisting}
while (x > 0) do
  x++; \end{lstlisting} & \begin{lstlisting}
x = 0; \end{lstlisting}  \end{tabular}\end{center}
```

Here is what is displayed after compilation: [image: latex code lstlisting]

The problem is, the vertical line of the tabular goes too far. I have tried to play with the lstlisting parameters belowskip and aboveskip, and tried to use minipages too, but nothing seems to work properly.

<strike>My second problem is that using the code above, the second code ("x = 0;") is not aligned with the while.</strike>
*EDIT : the second issue is solved using minipages, thanks to cfr*

Do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: Use `minipage`s or `\parbox`es with `[t]` alignment for the second problem.

Comment: You might be interested in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210284/how-to-write-pseudocode-similar-to-code-presented-in-beautiful-code-by-j-r-h/217644#217644

Comment: Thanks Henri, I have a working solution using minipages and vrule. But I hoped I could use a tabular and no vrule to do this (this would be cleaner for me)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

We got the above image  with the assistance of  `array` package, you can change the width of columns as you like

```
% \usepackage{array}  


\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{p{3.9cm}|p{3.9cm}} 
 \begin{lstlisting}
while (x > 0) do
  x++; \end{lstlisting} &
   \begin{lstlisting}
x = 0; \end{lstlisting}  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I was searching for. I am not trying to change the width of columns, but the height of the vertical line.

Comment: Try to reduce  `\arraystretch` , example `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.2}`.