# How can I typeset code region comments to the left of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking for a way to add region comments to an algorithm. A comment should appear left of the listing and mark the corresponding code region by, for example, a large curly bracket. Like summaries for specific code regions.

**Edit 1**: See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHUJY.png). Like that but with the curly bracket and the comment left of the code.

**Edit 2**: [Here's the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51019/how-can-i-put-a-curly-brace-inside-an-algorithm-to-group-code-lines) to the corresponding question for the image from edit1.

I would like to see it as some kind of command to be easily reusable.

Do you have any idea how to achieve something like this?

Comment: Please give the poster time to respond before voting to close.

Comment: Have to give it a try before I can tell whether this is what I am looking for. I'll get back here later.

Comment: Alright, it's almost what I want... Aside from one thing: I need the comments relate to a region, not a single line. And the relation should be visualized by a curly bracket. Like in this image (sorry for stealing): http://i.stack.imgur.com/UHUJY.png but with the bracket and the comment left of the code.

Comment: @HendrikWiese: Any reason why you did not just link to the question instead of linking to an image? That image sure looks familiar :-). Linking to the question might be useful as a starting point to a solution for you, especially since you did not provide a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)

Comment: Oh, stupid me... to be honest, I haven't even thought about that... I'll edit my question accordingly. //edit Ah, and regarding the MWE: I still consider myself a beginner with LaTeX, just scratching the surface of what's possible. I'm afraid I'm not capable of providing an MWE with my current level of LaTeX knowledge...

Comment: I think the real answer here is going to depend on how you want to specify the comments. If it is inline with the code then the solution in [Source Code Margin Comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/source-code-margin-comments) will work. If you prefer to specify them outside of the code then that is a different thing all together. The point of a MWE is to set up the problem for someone trying to help. Just include a sample listing and how you want to actually specify where the comments go.  Furthermore, are you referring to a listing, or `algorithm` type of environments?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use `\alglinenumber` to automagicaly insert a `\tkizmark` at each line, and then *after* the algorithm you can insert comments via `\AddNote`. So, if you want to add a comment for lines 1 thru 5, and lines 7-9 you would use:

```
\AddNote[blue]{1}{5}{Comments for lines 1--5.}
\AddNote[red]{7}{9}{Comments for lines 7--9.}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- In case you have overlapping lines you need to adjust `\VerticalOffset` via

  ```
    \renewcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{0.15ex}%
  ```
- The is adapted from [How can I put a curly brace inside an algorithm to group code lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51019/how-can-i-put-a-curly-brace-inside-an-algorithm-to-group-code-lines).
- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### References:

- Related Question: [Source Code Margin Comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/source-code-margin-comments)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\SpaceReservedForComments}{2.5cm}%
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{-0.5em}%
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{0.7ex}%
\newcommand*{\AddNote}[4][]{%
    %% #1 = draw options
    %% #2 = top line number to start comment from
    %% #3 = bottom line number where comment ends
    %% #4 = text of comment
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,red, #1]
            ($(#3)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) --  ($(#2)+(\HorizontalOffset,\VerticalOffset)$)
            node [align=left, text width=\SpaceReservedForComments-1.0em, pos=0.5, anchor=east] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\makeatletter% Add a \tkizmark for each line so we can reference it later
    \algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\tikzmark{\arabic{ALG@line}}\tiny#1:}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicgoto}{\textbf{go to}}%
\algnewcommand{\Goto}[1]{\algorithmicgoto~\ref{#1}}%
\begin{algorithm}[1]
\hspace*{\SpaceReservedForComments}{}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\SpaceReservedForComments\relax}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$} \Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}  \Comment{We have the answer if r is 0} \label{marker}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile 
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \State \Goto{marker}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}%
% ---------------
% Now insert all to comments that we desire on specific line numbers:
\AddNote[blue]{1}{5}{Comments for lines 1--5.}
\AddNote[red]{7}{9}{Comments for lines 7--9.}
% ---------------
\end{minipage}%
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```