# How can I typeset Greek letters in listings?

Tags: listings, greek

Is it possible (and if yes, of course how) to use Greek letters within `lstlisting` (of the `listings` package)? However, `\epsilon`, for instance, puts of course exactly that and not a Greek epsilon.

I have read in the documentation that it is possible to write e.g. Greek comments, but that is not what I want to do. I'm using `lstlisting` to write EBNF and would like to use an `\epsilon` for "empty".

Comment: It might help you to check out the documentation of the package, specifically section 4.14 about escaping to LaTeX.

http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf

Comment: Thanks! There's the answer. For future reference, I added an answer to the question.

Comment: Another example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8860/963

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Thanks to Mythio, I found the answer:*

Use `texcl=<true|false>` or `mathescape=<true|false>` to use the inline math-evironment `$\epsilon$` (see section 4.14 of the documentation)

Comment: You should mark this as the answer (if thats possible for your own posts)

Comment: Yes, I tried. But I can only do so in 2 days it says. But I will as soon as the system let's me to.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Could you update the answer to be more explicit? e.g. where do I write `texcl=<true|false>`?