# Emphasizing some parts of string in lstlisting

Tags: formatting, listings

I need to stress out some parts of string in `lstlisting`. I tried with `\emph{}`, but I got the verbatim result. Is there any way to that?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
Array1: 78 54 31 54 92 86 23 54 65 54 54 38 100 92 86 59 54 70 \emph{59 54 91 65 54 31 54 31 54 70 100 91 92 55 70 54 51 61 91 65 59 54 38 54 81 61 92 59 54 38 54 96 61 92} 59 54 38 54 81 54 92 90 54 92 88 36 65 59 54 38 54 101 61 92 59 54 38 54 96 61 92 59 54 38 54 101 54 92 90 54 92 88 88 86 98 115 54 70 54 66 89 54 91 65 54 54 38 75 54 70 91 92 59 54 38 54 31 54 70 61 91 92 54 31 54 31 54 70 54 91 92 88 88

Array2: 59 54 38 54 81 61 92 59 54 38 54 96 61 92 59 54 38 54 81 54 92 90 54 92 
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: related: [How can I highlight some lines from source code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8851)

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}




\lstset{moredelim=[is][\itshape]{[}{]}}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
Array1: 78 54 31 54 92 86 23 54 65
 54 54 38 100 92 86 59 54 70 
[59 54 91 65 54 31 54 31 54 70
 100 91 92 55 70 54 51 61 91 
65 59 54 38 54 81 61 92 59 54 38 54 96 61 92]
59 54 38 54 81 54 92 90 54 92 88 36 65 59
 54 38 54 101 61 92 59 54 38 54 96 61 92 59
 54 38 54 101 54 92 90 54 92 88 88 86 98 11
5 54 70 54 66 89 54 91 65 54 54 38 75 54 
70 91 92 59 54 38 54 31 54 70 61 91 92 54
 31 54 31 54 70 54 91 92 88 88

Array2: 59 54 38 54 81 61 92 59 54 38 54 96 
61 92 59 54 38 54 81 54 92 90 54 92 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Delimiters are `[` and `]` and `i` means they are invisible.

[image]