# How do I get selective bold in Verbatim?

Tags: verbatim, bold

I previously wrote a computer professional book in which I showed what the user typed on the console and the computer's resultant output. The way I liked to do this was with everything in courier and with the user's input in **bold**. Something like this:

```
<tt>
$ <b>echo foo</b>
foo
$
</tt>
```

I typed this as HTML because I don't know how to do this in Markdown (what StackExchange uses) and I don't know how to easily do it in LaTeX. I can certainly do it with `\texttt{\$ \textbf{echo foo}}`,  but I would rather not have to quote everything.

I don't want to use lstlisting as recommended by [Using bold/italic text inside listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/using-bold-italic-text-inside-listings), because I don't want LaTeX deciding what's bold.

Any other recommendations?

Comment: But you _can_ decide yourself with `listings`, and much easier than with plain `verbatim`...

Comment: See [How can I highlight some lines from source code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8851/5049) and [Emphasizing some parts of string in lstlisting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114721/5049) for similar questions

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've read the `listings` doc and can't figure out how to highlight a particular part of a line. I've also looked at the http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8851/5049 and it does seem like a lot of overhead. I gather that there is no easier way? This is, unfortunately, something that LaTeX doesn't seem to make easy.

Comment: something like `\lstset{moredelim=[is][\bfseries]{[}{]}}` (as in the answer to the second of the linked questions) does not seem too complicated to me...

Comment: Ah. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code Sort of does it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only need `fancyvrb` and not the full fledged `listings` package, you can do it quite easily with the `commandchars` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand\userinput[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\usepackage{tgcursor}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
$ \userinput{echo foo}
foo
$
\end{Verbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\#\[\]]
$ #userinput[echo \]
> #userinput[foo]
foo
$
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The triple of escaped characters can consist of anything is not used in the `Verbatim` environment.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option, that is less flexible than egreg's, is to use the `alltt` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
$ {\bf echo foo}
foo
$
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This makes the section bold, but it's not in typewriter font.

Comment: @crclayton True.  To correct that, it would in principle be enough to change `{\bf` to `\textbf{`, but in practice this gives non-bold typewriter font, likely because the appropriate combination is not found.  egreg fixes that by adding the package `tgcursor`.