# How to highlight php code in a HTML document and the document itself?

Tags: listings, highlighting

how can I highlight php code in a HTML document and the document itself?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo "Hello world!"; ?></h1>

<?php phpinfo();?>
</body>
```

I usually I use the listings package, but I don't know how to change the language when the php-Tag starts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code