# How to use onslide in a listing?

Tags: beamer, xetex, listings, animations

I need to animate single contiguous code listings by showing and hiding parts of code using `\onslide`. However, TeX is complaining. How can I achieve this? I tried the advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code) but it didn't work.

**Minimum working sample:**

```
\documentclass[utf8,pdf,aspectratio=169,handouts]{beamer}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Hello (*@ \onslide<2-> @*) world
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine, but as it's `beamer` you need a `frame` environment, and as this is verbatim text, you need the frame to be `fragile`, i.e.

```
\documentclass[utf8,pdf,aspectratio=169,handouts]{beamer}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello (*@\onslide<2->@*)world
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I removed some spaces in the above code, but not before generating the screenshot below, so the code gives less space between the words.

[image]