# Changing multiple properties within lstlisting in annimations

Tags: beamer, listings

Currently I am in the process of preparing a C++ training with the beamer package. So far everything is great!

From the answer to [How can I highlight some lines from source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85628/108675) I grabbed a nice solution of highlighting code step by step.
Since I have most of the time not much space below the code examples, I tend to explain certain lines in the code with C++ comment.

So with the code from [Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3751/daniel) I set the linebackgroundcolor. Is there a way to set at the same time an other lstlisting property like the commentstyle? My idea here is that the default color for the commentstyle is white and only in the highlighted sections I set a different color, e.g. green. (I tried simply to stay with white, but the contrast between the orange of the box and the white of the comment is from my point of view to low). For better illustration, see please the image below.

[image: Example image]

Many thanks in advance!

Here is my Latex code excerpt.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Goettingen}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgf, pgffor}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage{caption}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% custom makros
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=tr,                   % sets the caption-position to top
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},      % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={/*}{*/},           % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  language=C++,                    % the language of the code
  otherkeywords={*,...},           % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=1,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
  tabsize=2,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

%=====================================================================================================
% Define background box capabilities for source code listings
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code?lq=1
%=====================================================================================================

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \btIfInRange{number}{range list}{TRUE}{FALSE}
%
% Test in int number <number> is element of a (comma separated) list of ranges
% (such as: {1,3-5,7,10-12,14}) and processes <TRUE> or <FALSE> respectively

\newcount\bt@rangea
\newcount\bt@rangeb

\newcommand\btIfInRange[2]{%
    \global\let\bt@inrange\@secondoftwo%
    \edef\bt@rangelist{#2}%
    \foreach \range in \bt@rangelist {%
        \afterassignment\bt@getrangeb%
        \bt@rangea=0\range\relax%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{ ( #1 >= \bt@rangea) && (#1 <= \bt@rangeb) }%
        \ifnum\result=1\relax%
            \breakforeach%
            \global\let\bt@inrange\@firstoftwo%
        \fi%
    }%
    \bt@inrange%
}
\newcommand\bt@getrangeb{%
    \@ifnextchar\relax%
        {\bt@rangeb=\bt@rangea}%
        {\@getrangeb}%
}
\def\@getrangeb-#1\relax{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \bt@rangeb=100000%   \maxdimen is too large for pgfmath
    \else%
        \bt@rangeb=#1\relax%
    \fi%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \btLstHL<overlay spec>{range list}
%
% TODO BUG: \btLstHL commands can not yet be accumulated if more than one overlay spec match.
% 
\newcommand<>{\btLstHL}[1]{%
  \only#2{\btIfInRange{\value{lstnumber}}{#1}{\color{orange!30}\def\lst@linebgrdcmd{\color@block}}{\def\lst@linebgrdcmd####1####2####3{}}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{scoped enums}
    \begin{lstlisting}[
                     linebackgroundcolor={%
                         \btLstHL<2>{2}%                     
                         \btLstHL<3>{3-9}%
                         \btLstHL<4>{15}%
                         \btLstHL<5>{17}%
                         \btLstHL<6>{20}%                         
                    }
    ]

enum class Weekdays {     // enum type
  Monday,                 // enumerated values
  Tuesday,
  Wednesday,
  Thursday,
  Friday,
  Saturday,
  Sunday
};

auto today = Weekdays::Monday;

enum class HttpCodes {
  Continue = 100,         // initialized with 100
  OK = 200,
  Created,                // initialized with 201
  NotFound = 404,
  InternalError = 500,
  Error = InternalError   // initialized with 500 too
};    
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```