# LaTex Beamer highlighting wrapped lines in lstlisting

Tags: beamer, listings

I need to highlight full code lines in lstlisting and I'm using the solution provided in this [stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85628).

However, long wrapped lines (i.e., when "breaklines" is used in lstlisting) are not highlighted properly. Only the first part of the line (before the break) gets highlighted.

For example

[image]

The source for the image above

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf, pgffor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd} % see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \btIfInRange{number}{range list}{TRUE}{FALSE}
%
% Test in int number <number> is element of a (comma separated) list of ranges
% (such as: {1,3-5,7,10-12,14}) and processes <TRUE> or <FALSE> respectively

\newcount\bt@rangea
\newcount\bt@rangeb

\newcommand\btIfInRange[2]{%
    \global\let\bt@inrange\@secondoftwo%
    \edef\bt@rangelist{#2}%
    \foreach \range in \bt@rangelist {%
        \afterassignment\bt@getrangeb%
        \bt@rangea=0\range\relax%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{ ( #1 >= \bt@rangea) && (#1 <= \bt@rangeb) }%
        \ifnum\result=1\relax%
            \breakforeach%
            \global\let\bt@inrange\@firstoftwo%
        \fi%
    }%
    \bt@inrange%
}
\newcommand\bt@getrangeb{%
    \@ifnextchar\relax%
        {\bt@rangeb=\bt@rangea}%
        {\@getrangeb}%
}
\def\@getrangeb-#1\relax{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \bt@rangeb=100000%   \maxdimen is too large for pgfmath
    \else%
        \bt@rangeb=#1\relax%
    \fi%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \btLstHL<overlay spec>{range list}
%
% TODO BUG: \btLstHL commands can not yet be accumulated if more than one overlay spec match.
% 
\newcommand<>{\btLstHL}[1]{%
  \only#2{\btIfInRange{\value{lstnumber}}{#1}{\color{orange!30}\def\lst@linebgrdcmd{\color@block}}{\def\lst@linebgrdcmd####1####2####3{}}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Test}
\framesubtitle{Test}
\begin{columns}
\column{\dimexpr\paperwidth-20pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines,linebackgroundcolor={\btLstHL<1>{1}},basicstyle={\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}]
111111111111 1111111111111 1111111111111 11111111111111 1111111111111 1111111111111
222222222222 2222222222222 2222222222222 22222222222222 2222222222222 2222222222222
\end{lstlisting}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to highlight the entire line of 1s.

Comment: Can you please make your code fragment compilable?

Comment: @samcarter "compatible" as in it would compile? I've copied all the macro from the stackexchange answer I've pointed out.