# How to highlight code inside verbatim environment?

Tags: verbatim, code

I am writing a book containing tutorials and I need to show code:

```
Write this: 

\begin{verbatim}
function doit() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
\end{verbatim}

And then add these lines:

\begin{verbatim}
function doit() {
  var s = "Hello";
  console.log(s);
}
\end{verbatim}
```

I would like to highlight `var s = "Hello";` so that it is clear it is the new code added. I would like to set a different color for this text so the new line appears black and the rest appears grey.

How do I achieve this?

This is with a very standard LaTeX document, so I did not include the whole file.
fg

Comment: There are several packages for that such as `listings` and so on.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option with [`fancyvrb`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) where you can change the formatting of specific lines; the code should be self-explanatory:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor}

\begin{document}

Write this: 

\begin{Verbatim}
function doit() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
\end{Verbatim}

And then add these lines:

\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=2
    \textcolor{red}{#1}% Format specific line
  \else
    #1% Else, do nothing different
  \fi
}
\begin{Verbatim}
function doit() {
  var s = "Hello";
  console.log(s);
}
\end{Verbatim}

\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}{}% Clear how lines are formatted differently
\begin{Verbatim}
function doit() {
  var s = "Hello";
  console.log(s);
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

It should work for elementary setups and small code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Took this:
[How can I highlight some lines from source code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code)

Made this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,listings,xcolor}

    \lstnewenvironment{teX}[1][]
      {\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
       numbers=left,numberstyle=\normalsize,stepnumber=1,numbersep=5pt,
       breaklines=true,
       %firstnumber=last,
           %frame=tblr,
           framesep=5pt,
           basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
           showstringspaces=false,
           keywordstyle=\itshape\color{blue},
          %identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
           stringstyle=\color{maroon},
        commentstyle=\color{black},
        rulecolor=\color{black},
        xleftmargin=0pt,
        xrightmargin=0pt,
        aboveskip=\medskipamount,
        belowskip=\medskipamount,
               backgroundcolor=\color{white}, #1
    }}
    {}
    \begin{document}


Write this: 

\begin{teX}
function doit() {
console.log("Hello");
}
\end{teX}

And then add these lines:

\begin{teX}
function doit() {
(*@ \hl{var s = "Hello";} @*)
console.log(s);
}
\end{teX}

    \end{document}
```

Got this:

[image: Result]