# How to color lines in code using listling?

Tags: listings

I have a file with a code and I would like to insert it directly from the file in listings that is defined in some way. I need to color lines starting with #. How to do that please?

in.txt

```
# Code
This is code
# This is code
k
l
```

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  listing options={basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\mylisting[label=input]{Name}{in.txt}
\end{document}
```

I read for instance [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code/8860#8860), but I don't understand it.

This is output now:

[image]

The desired output is the first and third lines red, for instance.

Comment: Do you _need_ listings or you just want to colour lines after a `#`?

Comment: I would like to have similar output as now. I have just defined mylistling.

Comment: can you pleas add pictures of your current output and your desired output?

Comment: I added the picture

Comment: I think that package fvextra does what you require. It allows you to highligh a line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the listings package, the character(s) that indicate a comment can be specified using the option `morecomment`. The color of the comments can be set with the option `commentstyle`. Using only `listings` you normally put these options in a `\lstset` command, while with `tcolorbox` the options go into the `listing options` option of `\newtcblisting`. However, for `morecomments` the method of using `listing options` does not work, so it needs to be set by `lstset`. Additionally, the `#` character must be escaped because it is also used to denote arguments in LaTeX commands.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  listing options={basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{orange},
  %morecomment=[l]{\#}, % does not work
  },
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
% set comment character here instead
\lstset{morecomment=[l]{\#}}
\mylisting[label=input]{Name}{in.txt}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to Marin's answer but without `\lstsset`. (It took me a while to understand one has to add extra braces to make it work. That is, you need `morecomment={[l]{\#}}` rather than `morecomment=[l]{\#}` to hide the `[...]` from the parser. Now looking at it it is sort of obvious.) You can then put everything in the definition of the `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  listing options={basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    morecomment={[l]{\#}},
    commentstyle={\color{red}}},
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\mylisting[label=input]{Name}{in.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much