# How to zoom in in beamer algorithm package?

Tags: beamer, algorithms

I will be using the beamer class for my presentation. I want to present the algorithm line by line in such a way that the line on which I am working should get zoomed or lensed or highlighted. See my working code given below:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]\footnotesize

\SetAlgoLined

\textbf{Line 1} \\~\\

Line 2 \\


\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: There is nothing to zoom in in the beamer package.

Comment: Look for the `\framezoom` command, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130110/121799).

Comment: If you want to highlight line by line have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8375/36296 (possibly with `\alert` instead of `\uncover`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I have misinterpreted "zoom". Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,overlay-beamer-styles,fit}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}[H]\footnotesize

\SetAlgoLined

\tikzmarknode{1}{\textbf{Line 1}} \\~\\

\tikzmarknode{2}{Line 2} \\

\end{algorithm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[visible on=<1>,fit=(1),draw=red]{};
\node[visible on=<2>,fit=(2),draw=red]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you were to use `listings` instead, you could use the full potential of `tikzmark`, see e.g. [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337633/121799).

**OLD ANSWER**: You can use `\framezoom` in beamer. Algorithms are no exceptions.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An algorithm}
\framezoom<2><3>[border=2](-0.6cm,-0.1cm)(2cm,2cm)
\begin{algorithm}[H]\footnotesize

\SetAlgoLined

\textbf{Line 1} \\~\\

Line 2 \\

\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want only zoomed in not the effect.

Comment: @Isla_Bonita Sorry about that. I added something. Is that what you want?